Google API list reviews - 403 forbidden
I'm trying to implement fetching Google reviews for my business in Laravel using google/apiclient but I keep getting response code 403 Forbidden after my GET request.
$client = new Google\Client();
$serviceAccountKeyFilePath = storage_path('key-json.json');
$client->setAuthConfig($serviceAccountKeyFilePath);
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php');

$accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();

if (isset($accessToken['access_token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken['access_token']);
} else {
    return;
}


$clientID = 'my-client-id';
$placeID = 'my-place-id';

$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$url = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/' . $clientID . '/locations/' . $placeID . '/reviews';

$response = $httpClient->get($url, [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken['access_token'],
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
    ],
]);

dd($response);

I enabled these APIs in my account:

My Business Account Management API
My Business Business Information API
My Business Place Actions API
Places API
Places API (New)

But still I keep getting this
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response {#1670 ▼
  -reasonPhrase: "Forbidden"
  -statusCode: 403
}

I'm kinda confused and I can't see what I am missing here.

here is the same problem
